# A friend sent me a snippet I don't understand. How does this work?

Tags: c, pointers, ansi-c

I spent some time trying to understand what was going on with this code but in the end I couldn't fully figure it out.

```c
void knock_knock(char *s){
 while (*s++ != '\0')
  printf("Bazinga\n");
}

int main() {
 int data[5] = { -1, -3, 256, -4, 0 };
 knock_knock((char *) data);
 return 0;
}
```

I was surprised when I saw it didn't print 'Bazinga' 5 times, but 8. My next thought was that it was just iterating over the length of the pointer, so it would make sense that it printed 8 times. But, then I changed the first number of the array from -1, to check whether the data truly was relevant or not, and this is where I was confused. It didn't print 8 times anymore, but just once. Why?

Comment: The function is pointing int values (4 bytes) with a char pointer that point chars (1 bytes).....

Comment: Add `printf ("%08X - %08X - %08X\n", data[0], data[1], data[2]);` before the function call and see the output...

Comment: Doesn't this invoke undefined behaviour?

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please avoid to write a [wall of text](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text).

Comment: @George I don't think so, I think accessing stuff as `char` is generally OK. Don't quote me on that though, haven't read the standard this morning. :)

Comment: @unwind alright, cheers for the response :)

Comment: Sorry for the wall of text, just wanted to explain what I tried. If you didn't want to read the wall of text you could have just answered the question in the title and it would've been perfectly fine either way... Anyways thanks for taking the time to answer, I'll take a look now.

Comment: @George I don't think so: is, for example, how `memcpy` & so. work. Mayby is violating strict aliasing rules.

Comment: "I saw it didn't print 'Bazinga' 5 times" --> Why did you expect 5 versus maybe 4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the following code

```
#include<stdio.h>

void knock_knock(char *s)
{
    while (*s++ != '\0')
        printf("Bazinga\n");
}

int main()
{
    int data[5] = { -1, -3, 256, -4, 0 };
    printf("%08X - %08X - %08X\n", data[0], data[1], data[2]);
    knock_knock((char *) data);
    return 0;
}
```

You can see that HEX values of `data` array are

```
FFFFFFFF - FFFFFFFD - 00000100
```

Function `knock_knock` print `Bazinga` until the pointed value is `0x00` due to

```
while (*s++ != '\0')
```

But the pointer here is pointing chars, so is pointing a single byte each loop and so, the first `0x00` is reached accessing the "first" byte of third value of array.

Answer (score 4):

You need to look at the bytewise representation of data in the integer array `data`. Assuming an integer is 4 bytes, The representation below gives the numbers in hex

```
-1    -->  FF FF FF FF
-3    -->  FF FF FF FD
 256  -->  00 00 01 00
 -4   -->  FF FF FF FC
 0    -->  00 00 00 00
```

The array `data` is these numbers stored in a **Little- Endian** format. I.e. the LSbyte comes first. So,

```
data ={FF FF FF FF FD FF FF FF 00 01 00 00 FC FF FF FF 00 00 00 00};
```

The function `knock_knock` goes through this data bytewise and prints `Bazinga` for every non-zero. It stops at the first zero found, which will be after 8 bytes.

(Note: Size of Integer can 2 or 8 bytes, but given that your pointer size is 8 bytes, I am guessing that size of integer is 4 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to understand what occurs here if to output the array in hex as a character array. Here is shown how to do this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int data[] = { -1, -3, 256, -4, 0 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( data ) / sizeof( *data );

    char *p = ( char * )data;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N * sizeof( int ); i++ ) 
    {
        printf( "%0X ", p[i] );
        if ( ( i + 1) % sizeof( int ) == 0 ) printf( "\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF 
FFFFFFFD FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF 
0 1 0 0 
FFFFFFFC FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF 
0 0 0 0
```

So the string `"Bazinga"` will be outputted as many times as there are non-zero bytes in the representations of integer numbers in the array. As it is seen the first two negative numbers do not have zero bytes in their representations.

However the number `256` in any case has such a byte at the very beginning of its internal representation. So the string will be outputted exactly eight times provided that `sizeof( int )` is equal to `4`.